# Comportamento do refresh (nCurses)

Tags: c, ncurses

Estive estudando recentemente a biblioteca ncurses e acabei me deparando com uma dúvida: O que exatamente a função refresh deve fazer?

Pesquisando um pouco eu entendi que ela deveria atualizar a tela, mostrando a saída formatada. Basicamente faria todas as mudanças na "tela" em buffer e só após o refresh que realmente a saída acabaria aparecendo.

Mas fazendo uns testes, eu percebi que saída aparece com ou sem o refresh. No programa abaixo é algo bem simples testando os inputs e manipulação de posição no mvprintw:

```
#include <ncurses.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
  char mesg[] = "Just a String";
  int row, col;

  initscr();
  getmaxyx(stdscr, row, col);

  while(true) {
    //refresh();
    mvprintw(row/2, (col - strlen(mesg))/2, "%s", mesg);

    mvprintw(row-2, 0, "This screen has %d rows and %d columns\n", row, col);

    char c = getch();
    if (c == 'e') { row++; }
    else if (c == 'q') { row--; }
    else if (c == 'a') { col--; }
    else if (c == 'd') { col++; }
  }

  getch();
  endwin();

  return 0;
}
```

Retirando o refresh ou colocando ele em qualquer parte do código, sendo dentro do loop ou fora, aparentemente não muda nada na saída do programa.

Qual exatamente é a funcionalidade do refresh()??

Comment: meu palpite é que quando getch é chamada é feito um refresh automático